# How to return an enum from a class using generic enum type in Java

Tags: java, generics, enums

I've got a class that I'd like to use a generic enum type in, like this:

```
public class PageField<E extends Enum<E>>{
}
```

It seems like I should be able to have a getter method inside that class that then could return an enum `<E>` instance, like this:

```
public E getSelectedValue() {
    String value = getValueFromElement(this.id);
    return E.valueOf(value);
}
```

But i keep getting the following error:

> Inferred type 'java.lang.Object' for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should extend 'java.lang.Enum'

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot call the method `valueOf` on `E`: it is not an object, it is just a type parameter.

What you should do is pass the `Class` of the current enum type parameter so that you can use it to retrieve the enum value:

```
public class PageField<E extends Enum<E>>{

    private Class<E> enumClass;

    public PageField(Class<E> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }

    public E getSelectedValue() {
        String value = getValueFromElement(this.id);
        return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, value);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to retrieve the class of the type `E` because of type erasure, so you need to give it explicitely.

Comment: What he can do, to get the type of a class is to create a wrapper, storing object he is interested in and class variable which will contain type of stored object.

Answer (score 3):

The actual error message from the compiler is

```
Error:(6, 17) java: method valueOf in class java.lang.Enum<E> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Class<T>,java.lang.String
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Since the actual type of the enum is unknown, calling `valueOf(String)` is impossible, and the compiler thinks you're trying to call

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType,
                                            String name)
```

That's actuall the method you should call. But that means that your generic class needs to have a reference to the Class of the enum. Just as EnumSet does, for example. See the answer of @Tunaki for an example.